# Creating referenced nodes together with parent node

Tags: 6, entities

I've 4 node types(Area1-4) which all contain a field of node type of Address. Since address is common to all four nodes, I want each of them to link to Address node as node reference just to save space.

I'll have common people accessing sites so when one visitor tries to create Area1 he'll be confused as address field would require him/her to link to Address node.
That means one'd need to create Address node first which is difficult to explain to site users.

**What I want is single form where one'd enter Address details first followed by Area nodes.
What is the best way to handle this situation?**

Comment: Have you seen this (similar) stackoverflow.com Q&A? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369189/how-to-add-and-relate-a-node-within-the-parent-nodes-add-form-in-drupal

Comment: There isn't any solution in this thread but the question is same as mine. Also I'm don't yet understand if Node Relationships suggested in it may be useful