# Wizard or Form to create 5 nodes of 3 content types

Tags: forms

I'm building a genealogy site. One of the most important use cases is to create an individual. I want to use a single form to capture information that will be used to create up to five nodes after clicking submit. I've done a bunch of research, and found lots of stuff partially represented by the links below, but I haven't found anything that will do this. Can you point me to any modules to that do this? Or will I need to write my own module for this?

New Individual form captures the following fields:

- Birth Given & Surnames
- Current checkbox (checked if it's still individual's current name)
- End date, if not current name
- Current Given & Surnames - if different from birth
- Start Date - if applicable
- Date of Birth
- Place of Birth
- Date of Death
- Place of Death

The form then creates the following five nodes:

1. Individual node - with Title
2. Name node for birth name
3. Name node for current name (if different from birth name)
4. Event node for birth
5. Event node for death

Nodes 2-5 would have ER field_individual, to link back to the individual to which they are related.

Below are links to some of the resources I have found which are similar, but do not actually do what I'm looking to do:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_wizard_full_title
- https://www.sitepoint.com/building-multi-page-wizard-like-form-drupal/
- https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2008-06-06/adding-multiple-nodes-at-once
- https://www.webwash.net/create-multiple-nodes-from-a-single-page/
- [Creating Nodes and Referenced Nodes at Same Time](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27037/creating-nodes-and-referenced-nodes-at-same-time)
- https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2007-11-18/multiple-node-types-in-one-module
- https://www.drupal.org/project/pageroute

Comment: Leymannx - Thanks for feedback. I thought I was being specific about asking if there was a module that does what I need, or if I need to build one. Looks like GiorgosK gave me some valuable guidance below.

Comment: I would start by looking at hook_entity_presave in a custom module. This will save you quite a lot of grief as you can create or update your referenced nodes at the same as editing the "Individual node" (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need a custom module to do that

An outline of what your module should be doing

- Create a simple module using [the docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules) or following a [simple module tutorial](https://befused.com/drupal/first-drupal8-module) or by studying the [examples module](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples)
- Extend it by creating a form using [drupal 8 form API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/introduction-to-form-api)

  - Validate on submit that the input fields are filled in properly
- On formSubmit you should [create your nodes programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185442/programmatically-create-nodes)

  - Entity references can be created [using this as a guide](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/213379/programmatically-update-an-entity-reference-field)